# Use Iterator or array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, iterator

I mostly use Iterators because I return multiple objects (new X(new Y(new Z(new A)));) and without using iterator it could drain a lot memory. My code:

```
<?php
namespace Bulletpoint\Model\Wiki;

use Nette\Caching\IStorage;

final class CachedBulletpoints implements Bulletpoints {
    private $origin;
    private $storage;

    public function __construct(Bulletpoints $origin, IStorage $storage) {
        $this->origin = $origin;
        $this->storage = $storage;
    }

    public function iterate(): \Iterator {
        $key = __CLASS__ . '::' . __FUNCTION__;
        if($this->storage->read($key) === null) {
            $this->storage->write(
                $key,
                iterator_to_array($this->origin->iterate()),
                []
            );
        }
        return new \ArrayIterator($this->storage->read($key));
    }

    public function add(string $content, InformationSource $source) {
        $this->origin->add($content, $source);
    }
}
```

Then, another class, which can be wrapped by CachedBulletpoints:

```
<?php
namespace Bulletpoint\Model\Wiki;

use Bulletpoint\Model\Storage;

final class MySqlBulletpoints implements Bulletpoints {
    private $database;

    public function __construct(Storage\Database $database) {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function iterate(): \Iterator {
        $rows = $this->database->fetchAll(
            'SELECT ALL'
        );
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            yield new ConstantBulletpoint(
                $row['content'],
                new \DateTime($row['date'])
            );
        }
    }

    public function add(string $content, InformationSource $source) {
        $this->database->query(
            'JUST INSERT'
        );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php

$bulletpoints = new CachedBulletpoints(
    new MySqlBulletpoints(new PDODatabase),
    new MemoryStorage // Cache
);
$bulletpoints->iterate();
$bulletpoints->iterate();
$bulletpoints->iterate();
```

I am afraid of converting iterator to array, because it does not seem like a good solution and I probably entirely lose the power of Iterators here. So, should I use in this case array rather than Iterator or what should I use to cache Iterator? I have read about CachingIterator, but it does not seem like a solution for me, does it?

Thanks :)

Comment: I fail to see how caching helps in this implementation; the `$origin` is set in the constructor and thus is always available. Storing it in a cache seems complete redundant to me. Furthermore, using iterators over arrays seems more of a stylistic choice than one of functionality (unless you add your own logic to iterators, which is a whole debate on its own ;) ). If you have problems with memory usage you might get better results by inspecting what the contents of the iterator is than worrying about which container to use.

Comment: @Plenka I need to call method iterate for example three times in one class and I do not want to execute queries three times (It could be hidden in iterate implementation) but just once, that's reason why I use this cache. It just cache result for one request, then cache is invalidate, but it is not important, there is just an interface for caching. I need to pass $origin, because of getting data to cache. I do not have problems with memory, because I do not have enough data to test it properly. In fact, I'm just curious.

Comment: Then there's no clear answer to your question, as it seems that there might be iterator specific business logic not explained in the question that could have impact on the decision if arrays could substitute your iterators. About the cache: if you instantiate this class and use the iterator() method of that object multiple times the cache has a detrimental effect, as you're fetching data that is already available in the object. I can see that multiple instances of the class could share the cache, but in that case the fetching of the cache should be done in the constructor.

Comment: @Plenka I have edited my question. As you can see Iterator is Generator returned from yield. I use framework, where I just have to call it twice and I don't have another way how to do that differently.

Comment: That makes more sense. And in that case your implementation of caching it is not that helpful. You might want to move the fetching of the data and generation of the iterator to the constructor of the `MySqlBulletpoints` class, store it in an object property and return that in the iterate() method. That way no external cache is needed and the query is only executed once, even if the iterator() method is called multiple times. This is more important than the question of whether to use arrays or iterators, as those have much less impact on performance than fetching the data only once. ;)

Comment: @Plenka I'm not sure if I understand your advice, but have a look at this example: http://pastebin.com/KcCxriMD
It just doesn't work with iterators. Could you please show your example if I'm wrong? Thanks

Comment: The problem is your use of a generator. That is inherently meant for single use, after which it must be generated again. When trying to cache that you're effectively negating the purpose of a generator (a generator doesn't store yielded values, opening up memory after each iteration, which is undone by caching the results back in memory). What I was trying to say is to use a Iterator class for storing the values and returning that. And such an Iterator could easily be substituted with an array: http://pastebin.com/jwh01RKL